# Recursive algorithm to find the largest odd element of an unsorted array?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I had this question on a midterm today and my brain completely melted and I had no clue how to write the pseudocode or even how to approach the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems mildly unfair that they ask you to use recursion where it provides no particular benefit.

Answer (score 2):

This problem does not really call for a recursive solution, but if required, then use a divide-and-conquer approach: solve the problem for the left and right half of the array, then take the greatest of the two outcomes.

The recursion's base case occurs when the array has only one value: in that case verify whether it is odd. If so, return it, otherwise return some default value. I'll take minus infinity for that, meaning that if an array has no odd members, that will be the returned value.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript:

```js
function greatestOdd(arr, first=0, last=arr.length-1) {
    if (last == first) { // It's a single value
        if (arr[first] % 2 == 1) return arr[first]; // Odd
        else return -Infinity; // Even
    }
    let mid = (last + first) >> 1;
    let a = greatestOdd(arr, first, mid);
    let b = greatestOdd(arr, mid+1, last);
    return Math.max(a, b);
}

console.log( greatestOdd([5,4,2,7,6,10]) ); // 7
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply traverse the array and get the largest odd number. Recursion is not needed but traversal can be done recursively like:

```
int findLargest(index, arr)
    if ( index == arr.length - 1 )
        if ( arr[index] % 2 != 0 ) return arr[index]
        return MIN_VALUE
    else
        return arr[index] % 2 != 0 ? max(arr[index], findLargest(index + 1, arr)) 
                                   : findLargest(index + 1, arr)
```

You visit each element once and time complexity is `O(n)` but this uses `O(n)` space and can lead to stackoverflow because intermediate results are needed on the stack for the final result.

For example:

`max(arr[index], findLargest(index+1, arr))` is evaluated as:

`max(arr[index], max(arr[index+1], findLargest(index+2, arr)))` which is evaluated as :

`max(arr[index], max(arr[index+1], max(arr[index+2], findLargest(index+3, arr))))`
and so on...

The tail recursive version to avoid stack overflow:

```
int findLargestOdd(maxOdd, index, arr)
    if ( index == arr.length-1) return maxOdd;
    return arr[index+1] % 2 != 0 
          ? return findLargestOdd(max(maxOdd, arr[index+1]), index+1, arr)
          : return findLargestOdd(maxOdd, index+1, arr);
```

Here intermediate results needn't be stored on stack. You carry the result forward as : `max(maxOdd, arr[index])` or `maxOdd`

You could call this function as :

```
return arr[0] % 2 != 0 
     ? findLargestOdd(arr[0], 0, arr) 
     : findLargestOdd(MIN_VALUE, 0, arr)
```

Comment: Be aware that this will use O(n) stack space, which for larger arrays could produce a stack overflow error. Unless the compiler/parser supports and detects tail-recursion.

Comment: Those are two different statements. There are ways to avoid stack overflow and still use recursion.